# GLatLngBound from variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have images to overlay on google maps by using checkboxes. I made this script to not create the separate individual script for each overlay but it returns the error of proprty not supported in main.js of google maps api. However, i tried getting the output value in javascript alert and it returns the values as expected. Could anyone help please?

Here is the script.

```
function shImg(url,lat,lng) {
                var lat_ = "new GLatLng(" + lat + ")";
                var lng_ = "new GLatLng(" + lng + ")";
                var latlng = lat_ + ", " + lng_;
                var ticked_ = document.getElementById(url);

                var boundaries_ = "new GLatLngBounds(" + latlng + ")";
                var imgurl_ = "http://www.mywebsite.com/" + url + ".jpg";
                imageOverlay_ = new GGroundOverlay(imgurl_, boundaries_);
                map.addOverlay(imageOverlay_);
    if (!ticked_.checked)   {
                map.clearOverlays();
            //  imageOverlay_=null;
    }
        else {
                                alert(boundaries_);
                imageOverlay_.show();
```

}
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLatLng constructor takes two arguments, a latitude and a longitude. Similarly GlatLngBounds takes two arguments, a GlatLng for the south west corner and one for the north east. See the [api docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng) for more info.

Lastly why are you doing string concatenation all over the place? For example `"new GLatLng(" + lat + ")";` should be `new GLatLng(lat,lng);`

Comment: Thanks mate. Parsing it as string was the problem in fact. Cheers